# How to differentiate some LVITEMS (file or directory)?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, postmessage, clistctrl

So I am implementing a CListCtrl using `PostMessage(LVN_INSERTITEM,0,(LPARAM) lvitem)`. And I need a way to differentiate lvitems, so that later on when I will get a lvitem, to tell if it's a file or directory. I need to implement using `PostMessage`, so I don't know exactly when the item is inserted. I am allocating the item dynamically (storing the dynamically allocated memory pointer in the lParam attribute of the LVITEM structure, so after it is inserted I treat it's notification and deallocate the memory getting the address from the item).

Comment: Store a bool or enum in wParam?

Comment: Or just store additional data after the lvitem structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `lParam` member of the [`LVITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure to set custom data for you list item:

```
// custom structure to hold some information
struct listItem {
   int value;
   char path[MAX_PATH];
};

// initialize a custom object to hold a value and a path
LVITEM lvi;
listItem* pItem = new listItem();
pItem->value = 666;
sprintf(pItem->path,"c:\\\\xampp\\htdocs");

// initialize a LVITEM object
memset(&lvi, 0, sizeof(lvi)),
lvi.pszText = "My Folder";
lvi.mask = LVIF_PARAM | LVIF_TEXT;
// lParam points to our custom object
lvi.lParam = (LPARAM)pItem;
SendMessage(g_hwndLV, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvi);
```

**Note:** In this case you should free the memory pointed to by `lParam` using `delete`.

Comment: about that.....that idea is good, but unfortunately for me, lparam is already used, for storing the original pointer of the dynamically allocated LVITEM so that after it is inserted asynchronous with postmessage, i can process the notification, and get the original address from the newly inserted item, and deallocate it.

Comment: I was thinking about this,and yes i think i'm going to define a structure that holds the address, and a bool variable to determine file or directory, and set the strucutre to the lParam, and when i receive the LVN_INSERT_ITEM notification to dealocate the item address, i'm going to set it's item data too.

Answer (score 0):

You can set arbitrary data with [`CListCtrl::SetItemData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/936147y4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but you should use the method `CListCtrl::InsertItem` instead of using `PostMessage` (which is a low-level Win32 call, not MFC).

Comment: I know that i can set data with that function,but by using postmessage, i don't know when the message is going to be processed so i don't know when the item is inserted, and the only time i know about it's attribute is when i postmessage it. I need a different solution.

Comment: Then why are you using `PostMessage()` at all? Apart from not being idiomatic MFC code, it does not solve your problem. Why don't you use `CListCtrl::InsertItem()`?

Comment: @Andre - OP is posting the lvitem from a different thread?  That would explain the PostMessage and the need to deallocate the lvitem after the CListCtrl is updated, (the posting thread has malloced the lvitem but relinquished ownership by posting off its pointer - the receiving thread must then deallocate it after handling the message).

Comment: I know *that* the OP is using `PostMessage`, but I wanted to know *why* he is doing so without making wild guesses on my own. If the reason is like you assumed I would make a call across the threads and execute `CListCtrl::InsertItem` and `CListCtrl::SetItemData` there. So, let's see if the OP will return.

Comment: I know that i can solve this problem some other way, but i need to solve somehow using this particular method, with postmessage. but by using postmessage, i kind of need to set somehow different the data. I'm kind of new at these things, so it's hard for me to explain better, since it is a task, and that's the way i got to do it:).

Comment: Is it a task at work? Does it make sense? If not, you might change it by providing a better solution (i.e. learn to say *no*).

Comment: Yes it was a task. and it does make sense , but i am new here, and i want to learn new things, so i needed some other opinions. Thanks for all the answers.